# Calculate sum of many integers

Tags: java

I have written code to show me all the multiplies of the number 3 up to 1000(ex. 3,6,9,12,15...)

I have succeeded in displaying the numbers, but i want to make the program to automatically add together these numbers to a total sum(ex. 3 + 6 + 9 + 12 + 15...)

I am currently stuck on this problem, and greatly appreciate help! English is not my native language, so sorry for misspellings and such.

Here is the current code i have!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int nr3 = 0;
    int end = 1000; 

     while ( nr3 < end){
         nr3++;
         nr3++;
         nr3++;

         System.out.println(nr3);
     }
}
```

Comment: Just a tip: you can use nr +=3 to avoid some repetition in your code. PS Have faith in your English - it's good!

Comment: `nr3++;` thrice is the equivalent of `nr3 += 3;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new variable `sum` and add your `nr3` to it. Instead of repeatedly calling increment you can do `nr3 +=3;`

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int nr3 = 0;
       int end = 1000; 
       int sum=0;

       while ( nr3 < end){
          nr3 +=3;
          sum+=nr3;
          System.out.println( nr3);
      }
      System.out.println( sum);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make make an integer (say `int sum = 0`) And then add at then end of every while loop like

```
sum += nr3;
```

Then print out the sum after the loop, and you're done!

Answer (score 0):

use the below code:

```
          int nr3 = 0;
          int end = 1000; 
          int sum=0;

           while ( nr3 < end)
           {
               nr3 += 3;
               System.out.println( nr3);
              sum += nr3;
           }
           System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another solution to your problem which implies a code which is quite different. It is based on the fact that:

- summing all multiples of a certain number p in the range 0 to n is equivalent to summing all multiples in the range of 1 to n/p (integer division) then multiply by p;
- for any number x, 1 + 2 + ... + x == x * (x + 1) / 2.

Therefore the code is simple:

```
public static int allMultiples(final int multipleOf, final int upTo)
{
    final int limit = upTo / multipleOf;
    // The dividend is guaranteed to be an even number:
    // either limit or limit + 1 will be even
    return multipleOf * limit * (limit + 1) / 2;
}
```